# Excel VBA - Add hyphens to column A if column B contains specific letter

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, format, range

Please help a newbie.
Using Excel VBA, I am trying to format the text in column A with hyphens but only if column B contains the letter B.

I have found the code below, one which formats the cells in column A with hyphens, and another code which checks column B for the correct value, but cannot seem to combine them to work. Help please.
Thank you.

```
Sub AddDashes()
  Dim Cell As Range
  On Error GoTo NoFilledCells
  For Each Cell In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Cell.Value = Format(Replace(Cell.Value, "-", ""), "@@@@@-@@@-@@@@")
  Next
NoFilledCells:
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub ChangeColumn()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("B" & i).Value = "B" Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = "Formatted text with hyphens as above"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddDashes()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        If cell.Offset(0, 1) = "B" Then ' col B
            cell.Value = Format(Replace(cell.Value, "-", ""), "@@@@@-@@@-@@@@")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```